# Using boolean logic inside SUM function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server 2008, this query works:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CAST(isredeemed AS TINYINT)) AS totalredeemed,
FROM rewards
GROUP BY merchantid
```

It gives you the number of redeemed rewards by merchant. The `TINYINT` cast is need to avoid the error `Operand data type bit is invalid for sum operator.`

Now I'd like to do a similar query, but one that only finds rewards redeemed in the last few days. I tried this:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CAST((isredeemed & ( MIN(dateredeemed) > '2014-01-10 05:00:00')) AS TINYINT)) AS claimedthisweek,
FROM rewards
GROUP BY merchantid
```

and I get the error

> Incorrect syntax near '>'.

I also tried replacing `&` with `&&` and also with `AND`. But those don't work either.

How can I make the example work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question lacks detail to give an exact answer but you need to use a derived table or subquery for the calculation.

something like this

```
SELECT r1.merchantid, r2.claimedthisweek
FROM rewards r1
JOIN (
    SELECT merchantid, SUM(CAST(isredeemed AS INT)) claimedthisweek
    FROM rewards
    GROUP BY merchantid
    HAVING MIN(dateredeemed) > '20140101'
)  r2
```

Comment: yeah, this would definitely work and is probably the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this would work but it would count some twice:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(case when MIN(dateredeemed) > '2014-01-10 05:00:00' then 1 else 0 end )    
FROM rewards
GROUP BY merchantid
```

Comment: I'm getting: `Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery`

Comment: Yea, i had that comment in there...  what is isredeemed?

Comment: Just a true/false bit field

Comment: Do you need to use the `isredeemed` flag if the `dateredeemed` has been set?  Or can you add `isredeemed=1` to your where clause?

Comment: So this where the simplification I made when trying to clarify the problem in the post comes back to bite me.  I will update the post if necessary to clarify, but I'll just say that in the real problem yes, it's necessary.

Comment: Ok I will update the OP with full info, but the general question I'd really like the answer to is how to include arbitrarily complex boolean logic inside of sums like that.  i take it this is not possible from the answers so far....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44921/discussion-between-nix-and-jonah)

Answer (score 0):

This should be on the having clause, like this:

```
  SELECT 
  SUM(CAST((isredeemed AS TINYINT)) AS claimedthisweek
  FROM rewards
  GROUP BY merchantid
  HAVING MIN(dateredeemed) > '2014-01-10 05:00:00'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have other records I'm selecting that I don't want limited by a HAVING clause.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason not to do the filtering at the "where" clause level? That should work so long as all rows you're aggregating match the same criteria:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CAST(isredeemed AS TINYINT)) AS claimedthisweek
FROM rewards
WHERE dateredeemed > '2014-01-10 05:00:00'
GROUP BY merchantid
```

Comment: I have other records I'm selecting that I don't want limited by a WHERE or HAVING clause

Comment: Ah, per that other comment I guess this would also filter out the rows you don't want filtered out via HAVING.

Comment: I believe nix's answer will work without the MIN() around dateredeemed. I may be misunderstanding the context, but I _think_ it doesn't make sense to aggregate dateredeemed for each row--each row already has its own dateredeemed. The case expression will return a zero for each row that wasn't in the desired date range, so you'll only get a count of those that were.